# Equal Space between the legends in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am newbie in using d3 library, I am trying to  have equal space between the legends. In the current stage of my work -attached- does not provide equal spaces.

I would like to know how I could able to fix.

[image]

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 60 };

    self.drawLegends = function () {

            var legendData = [{ "color": "blue", text: "Normal Distribution" }, { color: "green", text: " Ave A" }, { color: "red", text: "Ave B" }]
            var legends = self.svg.selectAll("g legends").data(legendData);
            var legendBox = legends.enter()
                 .append("g")
                 .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(" + parseFloat((i + 1) * (($("#chart").width() - margin.left - margin.right) / 4)) + ",-10)" })

        var circles = legendBox.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return d.color })

        legendBox.append("text")
           .attr("dx", function (d) { return 10 })
           .attr("dy", function (d) { return 5 })
           .attr("fill","white")
           .text(function (d) { return d.text })
    },
```

Comment: Just to check: The coloured circles are even-spaced, do you mean that the position of the circles should be determined by the length of the text? If so, you could use `.getComputedTextLength()` on the text. Here's a fiddle I made which shows your problem - It's useful to create these to work on: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/7Le4tc92/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle with what I think you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/7Le4tc92/2/

When you first draw the `circle` and `text` in each `g` element, don't use a transform. Then, select each `g` and get the text length (using `getComputedTextLength()`) to calculate the translation you want:

```
svg.selectAll("g")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        var x_pos = d3.select(this).select("text").node().getComputedTextLength() + 20;
        x_offset = x_offset + x_pos;
            return "translate(" + (x_offset - x_pos + margin.left) + ", 20)"
    })
```